# what are tuning dots and how to effectively use them

Tags: rf

I've come across some template designs that have tuning dots included for RF matching. Unfortunately they are using a different dielectric than I am.

What are the basic principles of tuning dots (theoretical to purely mathematical would be great), and how do I then change their design to fit my own boards specifications?

NOTE- tuning dots are filled in the end design, this is merely how my importer displays them

[image: tuning dots in all their glory]
[image: blurry=better picture of the tuning dots]

Comment: A real picture might help.

Comment: what are the dimensions of the tuning pads and gaps between them?

Comment: @DakotaD .25 mm squares with .25 mm between squares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their purpose is to provide a means of adding variable length stubs for impedance matching.  A [wire bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_bonding) can be connected from the bondable gold surface of the microstrip center trace to the pad.  The bond wire will have an inductance value based upon bond height/length and wire thickness; the bond pad will have a known capacitance based upon the substrate dielectric and the pad geometry.

A very brief mention of their use can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FdSQSAC3_EwC&lpg=PA335&dq=microstrip%20tuning%20pad&pg=PA335#v=onepage&q=microstrip%20tuning%20pad&f=false).  Additionally, their use is discussed at [Microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/chip-wire-construction#chicken), where they are called "chicken dots".

Comment: @LegenDiary fixed bad link

Comment: I upvoted the answer. I'm checking with the original designer. If it's the same answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: no response. What you've said makes sense